# Why is Percy sometime spelled Perce?

Tags: harry-potter

The brother of the Weasley family, Percy is sometime spelled Perce whilst in dialog. Why is this? My edition of Harry Potter is (I believe) and adult cover. It illustrates grave stones, along with Ignotus Peverell's.

This is a quote directly from Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows; on my edition, Pg. 487, chapter thirty, The sacking of Severus Snape.

> "**Percy** spluttered into silence. Evidently he had not expected to run into most of his family."

Although when George used his name in dialog he says,

> "What made you see sense, **Perce**?"

Why is his name sometimes spelled Perce?

Comment: Same reason Jacob is sometimes spelled Jake?

Comment: I don't understand the people down voting: this is a legitimate, if simple, question about the expression of names in a popular work of fantasy. It is researched enough to include quotes to illustrate the question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I believe Perce is simply being used as a short form of Percy. Notice that it's Percy when he's mentioned by the author, but 'Perce' only when spoken to by other characters; characters use short forms, the author/narrator doesn't, as a rule.

Percy itself is a short form of Percival or Perseus; it's not much of a stretch to take the 'Perce' sound that is found in each of them and use it as a familiar form.

Think 'Duds' for Dudley.  Or 'Ron' for Ronald.

Comment: Good answer. However I've always seen nick names to be an easier, and a shorter word than the actual name. Percy, and Perce are just changing letters.

Comment: Ah, but the short form is for convenience when spoken; it is 1 syllable shorter verbally.

Comment: Understandable. How do you pronounce it?

Comment: As Martha indicated in her answer, Perce by itself is pronounced like 'Purse' (as in a term for a handbag, or what you do with your lips in some cases.)  Percy adds the sound of 'e' as in 'eeek!' or 'He' -- the result, the two syllable 'PUR-see.' [Here's a link to it being pronounced](http://inogolo.com/audio/Percy_5185.mp3)

Answer (score 13):

*Perce* (pronounced /purse/, more or less) is a nickname for *Percy*.